# heroku deployment - how to run a specific build?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I need to use Heroku as remote test platform, before deploying a MEAN stack app ( node + Angular + webpack) to a VPN for production
. 
In the package.json , I have 3 build scripts.
By default Heroku is running its own default build script ( however heroku-prebuild and heroku-postbuild scripts can be added)
I want hero to run my build:test script by default ...
Is it possible ? if yes , how ?
Then I guess I can start node with test environment, using :

```
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=test
```

my **package.json** scripts

```
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./bin/www",
        "build": "node_modules/.bin/del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
        "build:test": "node_modules/.bin/del-cli public/js/app&& ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.test.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts'",
        "build:prod": "node_modules/.bin/del-cli public/js/app&& ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts'"
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have a development and production flavor for our own app, which draws from the yeoman generator and all we had to do is this.

1. Go to Project's Setting section
2. Open Config Variables by clicking Reveal Config Vars button

Then set the value like this

[image]

Hope this helps!
If not do let me know how you solved it! Best!

Comment: thanks ... it's running ... I am now moving to test my stafing/production deployment to my VPN, and I'll use Heroku only for quick development tests...

Comment: Ah! Nice. Glad I could help.